# viewing fields with field_view_field after EntityFieldQuery doesn't work

Tags: entities, nodes, database

I'm using an EntityFieldQuery to load a node and try to access some of its fields, but can't seem to get any of the fields. The code is below:

```
$nodestoload = $query->execute();
$nids = array_keys($nodestoload['node']);
$nodes = entity_load('node', $nids);
print_r($nodes);
$output = field_view_field('node', $nodes, 'suppliername');
```

However, `$output` is returning an empty array. I can see that the node loads using the print_r. I've also tried various options (such as replacing 'node' with the actual bundle type). But nothing seems to be working... How do I access fields from a node that I loaded programmatically?

Comment: Names for fields added through the UI are prefixed with `field_`, any chance that's the problem?

Comment: When I try that I get a "EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids" error??

Comment: `field_view_field()` is for a single value, you just need to loop over `$nodes`...

Comment: Seems to have worked, thanks. Want to put it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is the following one.

```
$nodes_to_load = $query->execute();
if (isset($nodes_to_load['node'])) {
  $nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($nodes_to_load['node']));

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'suppliername');
    // ...
  }
}
```

[field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) accepts a single entity object, as second argument; you cannot pass it an array of entities.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only work if there is only a single value returned by your EFQ. Whatever you want to do with the nodes, you need to put in a `foreach()`:

```
$nodestoload = $query->execute();
foreach ($nodestoload as $loaded_node) {
  $nid = array_keys($loaded_node['node']);
  $node = entity_load('node', $nid);
  print_r($node);
  $output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'suppliername');
}
```